# What is R-Mail (not in Master Category List) Outlook category

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I just noticed that one of my email messages got a category that I did not create. I could not delete it in the Color Categories dialog box as its Delete button was grayed out,
but I could clear its check box, which removed it from the message.

Does anybody know what the R-Mail category is? I also want to know whether it could have been automatically removed if I hadn't cleared it in the dialog box.

I am using Outlook 2013 on Windows 10.

Thank you!

[R-Mail.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWWvB.png)

[R-MailCategory.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv29S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be the category on the message before you got this message in your Outlook. So it is listed as Not in Master Category List.

Similar thread for your reference:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother/outlook-category-not-on-master-category-list/ea392d9e-c12f-4acd-a14b-532be4128f58

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, @Sue.J! I saw that thread before posing my question, but I did not fully understand the explanation.

Based on your response, I sent an email with a category to my friend. He told me that he got a *white* category with the name I created and "not in Master Category List."

Mystery solved :)

Comment: Glad it helps. :)